# Making a 2x2 grid with divs fullscreen in html

Tags: css, html

I try to make a grid of 4 divs formed in a 2x2 position. Between those divs I want a border with a width of 1 pixel, basicly looking like this:

```
1|2
-+-
3|4
```

The divs need to be equal in their sizes and in total they need to be in full screen with any resolution. My first idea is to make 2 divs for the rows, and in each div 2 divs for the columns, floating left. So far I have the rows working perfectly but as soon as I add the border between the divs a scroll bar shows up. Clearly the border isn't included in the width: 50%. How can I manage to get this?

This is my code so far.

CSS

```
 html, body 
            {
                margin: 0;
                padding: 0;
                width: 100%;
                min-height: 100%;
            }

            .row
            {
                Width: 100%;
                Height: 50%;
             }

            .border
            {
                border-bottom: 1px solid black;
            }
```

HTML

```
<div class="row border" style="background-color: red;">

    </div>
    <div class="row" style="background-color: blue">

    </div>
```

I also tried to make the code work in a fiddle demo: [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/N6JuV/2/) but for some reason the height: 100% on body and/or html won't work.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Do you need something like this? I've made it from complete scratch...

[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/ZGMwG/)

What am doing here is having 4 `div` elements floated to the left, each `50%` wide and have used `box-sizing` property so that the borders don't interrupt the `div` alignment. These `div` elements are `50%` in `width` and are `50%` in `height`

```
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>

* {
    -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
    -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

html, body {
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
}

div {
    width: 50%;
    height: 50%;
    float: left;
}

div:nth-of-type(1) {
    background: #ccc;
}

div:nth-of-type(2) {
    background: #bbb;
    border-left: 1px solid #f00;
}

div:nth-of-type(3) {
    background: #aaa;
    border-top: 1px solid #f00;
}

div:nth-of-type(4) {
    background: #ddd;
    border-top: 1px solid #f00;
    border-left: 1px solid #f00;
}
```

Comment: This is perfect way to achieve it. Better than mine. Please update your link, it's not working.

Comment: Thank you! This works. Although I had some issues to get it working in the actual website I am building but in the end I could solve those issues as well. Seems you really have to be careful with min-height and height and position: absolute. But in the end it all worked like I wish it works. Thank you! And for the ending result and some adaptation a link to the fiddler who I needed it in the end: http://jsfiddle.net/ZGMwG/1/

Answer (score 4):

There is a nice css property `box-sizing` that you can set to `border-box` so that the widths of borders and padding are *included* in the width of an element. This way you can also add as much padding as you need to your `div`s without worrying that they become too wide.

You also don't actually need to wrap your two rows inside separate `div`s -- if you specify that a `div` should be 50% wide, exactly two will fit in a row if you `float` them `left`.

HTML

```
<div class="box">Box 1</div>
<div class="box">Box 2</div>
<div class="box">Box 3</div>
<div class="box">Box 4</div>
```

CSS

```
body, html {
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    height: 100%;
}

.box {
    box-sizing: border-box;
    float: left;
    width: 50%;
    height: 50%;
}

/* This is one way of adding borders, 
   if you *always* know that you have exactly 4 cells 
   aligned like this */
.box:first-child {
    border-bottom: 1px solid black;
    border-right: 1px solid black;
}
.box:nth-child(2) {
    border-bottom: 1px solid black;
}
.box:nth-child(3) {
    border-right: 1px solid black;
}
```

See http://jsfiddle.net/RBWXe/

The borders are a bit tricky, because as I understand, you want them in between your boxes, and not touching the edges of the screen. This requires you to specify exactly which sides of each box should have a border.

A fancier way of doing this, which would also allow you to change the number of boxes in your grid later, is to use a `background-color` for the `body` element which is your border colour, and have the boxes just half a pixel narrower than 50% (using the `calc` function), to accommodate the 1px space in between them. See http://jsfiddle.net/yhRBy/2/

Answer (score 0):

Check this fiddle:

`height` used instead of `min-height`

http://jsfiddle.net/N6JuV/7/

That's 2X2 grid you that want.

You just have to make sure that your widht % and margin % should add to 100%. You can even use decimal for smaller margins.

Eg. http://jsfiddle.net/N6JuV/8/

Comment: you should add code of jsfiddle since it gets down quite more time now a days

Answer (score 0):

Here is my solution

```
<div class="d-table">
   <div class="d-row">
       <div class="d-cell first"></div>
       <div class="d-cell first"></div>
   </div>
   <div class="d-row">
       <div class="d-cell first"></div>
       <div class="d-cell first"></div>
   </div>
</div>
```

And CSS

```
.d-table{
   display:table;
   table-layout:fixed;
   height:100%;
   width:100%; // Assuming you have already set 100% height and width to body and html
}
.d-row{
   display : table-row;
}
.d-cell{
   display : table-cell;
}
.first{
   width : 50%;
}
.second{
   width : 50%;
}
```

Demo here http://jsbin.com/osutos/1/edit